# Unable to run sudo apt update or sudo apt-get update due to hash sum mismatch

Tags: apt, 20.04

I am running Ubuntu on a VM and am trying to download some packages, but every time I run `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update`, I get a hash mismatch error. On looking up posts related to this, I even reset my sources list as was mentioned, but the error persists. Is there any other solution you might recommend? Is there something wrong with the installation itself?

This is what I get:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: When you say "reset my sources list", do you mean `/etc/apt/sources.list`? How did you reset it? Also, do you have anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: Yes I mean `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I used the sources list generator to generate new sources after backing up my old ones. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty.

Comment: Why provide only the summary error? without the actual line which contains the error?    All I currently can suggest is to read the actual error itself, not the summary (it's further up the listing, it's where I'd first look for clues).

Comment: @guiverc thank you that is helpful! No idea how I missed that. And my apologies for not providing enough details, I'm new around here and still figuring things out.